# Xcode - Profile and Optimize C++ Compile Times

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, llvm, compile-time

How can I profile and optimize the C++ Compile Times with Xcode?

I'm currently working on a C++ Game Project based on Cocos2d-x with 250+ Source Files. The compile time (without Cocos2d-x) is currently around 3.5 Minutes and I would like to find out where the compiler spends the most time and what I can do to optimize that.

I already did the most obvious things like always doing forward declarations and apply the "Include What You Use" paradigm.

The compiler is the latest Clang/LLVM of Xcode 8.

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers? That gave me a speedup factor 4 in one project that I inherited without them.

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a directory `/tmp/xcode_build_timings`, and rebuild your project. (Don't forget to delete it afterward).

Comment: This sounds interesting....could you be a bit more specific? What does it do? Where exactly should the folder be, etc.?

Comment: I provided the exact path for the folder. So I don't understand what you mean by "where exactly should the folder be"?
Then try to build your project after creating this folder, and check the content. It should provide timing for the build.

Comment: Okay, makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try ccache. Working well within Xcode for me if I re-define `CC` in the project settings. https://ccache.samba.org/

So, for example, install ccache via `brew install ccache`.
Then make a script that you keep in your project's source control that is something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
if type -p /usr/local/bin/ccache >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  export CCACHE_CPP2=true
  exec /usr/local/bin/ccache "${DEVELOPER_DIR}/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" "$@"
else
  exec "${DEVELOPER_DIR}/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" "$@"
fi
```

call it "ccache-clang" for example. Storing this script in your project's source control means that you can check it out on another machine which does not have ccache installed, and then it will just use the default Clang compiler.

Then in Xcode, under Build Settings for your project, add a "User Defined" setting of "CC", ands et it to the path to your script. "`${PROJECT_DIR}/ccache-clang`" for example.

This article is a great resource for getting this going.
https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2015/ccache-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: But isn't Xcode already doing that? Where did you redefine CC and to which Value? Does it help for profiling or optimizing? Please give a bit more insight into what exactly you do and what you achieve ;)

Comment: Xcode avoids re-compling files when it can, but ccache will actually fulfill compilation from an on-disk cache, so even a clean rebuild will be much faster. I added more detailed instructions

Comment: I've set it up now and it seems to work quite well, but it doesn't bring a really big improvement (yet). I've got some cache hits here and there but most of the time it compiles new. I also tried playing with settings from the article. Do you have some additional hints for me?

Comment: part of that issue can be because Xcode plays around with the derived data folder. You might try fixing that folder to a specific position, same with the build output. I don't recall the settings offhand, but because ccache uses the file path as part of the key, the way Xcode manages things can result in more misses

Comment: Ah yeah...that makes sense. Might this be something with the ccache base_dir? Did you set that to some value / to the derived folder or to the Source folder?

Comment: yes, the base_dir can help. You can also control the derived data location in the settings of Xcode http://meandmark.com/blog/2015/08/changing-xcodes-build-location/